# Creating Numpy structured array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

While brushing up my numpy skills, I've encounter the structured array.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> person_data_def = [('name', 'S6'), ('height', 'f8'), ('weight', 'f8'), ('age', 'i8')]
>>> person_data_def
[('name', 'S6'), ('height', 'f8'), ('weight', 'f8'), ('age', 'i8')]
```

What are `S6`, `f8` and `i8` in this context?

Comment: Here's a bit of bed time reading: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html.  This bit of code creates a compound `dtype`.

Comment: That's not a structured array, but a list of tuples describing a dtype. Please read the documentation carefully. SO is not a replacement for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing things up a little bit.

person_data_def is not a structured array but just a list of tuples. However, this list is used as the type for the structured array.
Adapting the example from the numpy documentation gives

`x = np.array([('Rex', 9, 81.0, 18), ('Fido', 3, 27.0, 20)], dtype=[('name', 'U10'), ('height', 'f8'), ('weight', 'f8'), ('age', 'i8')] )`

x can then be accessed by using

`x['name']` which will give you `array(['Rex', 'Fido'], dtype='<U10')`

`S6`, `U10`, `i8`, etc. are the datatypes and a little trickier to understand, but for example `i4` refers to a signed integer of size 32 bits (size marked by the number).
Also the `>`and `<` you will see are to distinguish between little and big endian (direction your computer read bytes). But I think they are set automatically if not specified other way.

See here for a more detailed description of the datatypes:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#arrays-dtypes-constructing